# Point Multiple IP Addresses to a Single Host Name

Tags: dns, hosts, hosts-file, hostname

Is it possible to have a single host name with multiple IP addresses? The hostname will be used to access a box in LAN with 192.168.x.y and from outside with IP w.x.y.z which is portforwarded to that box in a router.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking about. What do you think it means to point an IP address to a host name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use hostfile switching program like http://hostprofiles.codeplex.com/ (for windows and linux) and http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/29/switch-and-manage-multiple-hosts-files-with-gas-mask/ (for mac) to do that. You will have

home host file

```
192.168.x.y  myutilbox.twh
```

outside host file

```
w.x.y.z myutilbox.twh
```

You will switch the hostfile accordingly and use the hostname, "myutilbox.twh" to access your box.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple batch file or script to rotate between HOSTS files?

For example, this works on Windows when run as Administrator (you may have to un-hide your HOSTS file and make it writable first):

```
@echo off
set ThisDir=%CD%
cd /d %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc
ren hosts. hosts.tmp
ren hosts.other hosts.
ren hosts.tmp hosts.other 
cd /d %ThisDir%
```

Run it and it will swap HOSTS for HOSTS.OTHER and the next time you run it, it will switch them back.

Comment: your solution is simple and good. I don't know bash. How about including the flashing of DNS (Host Profiles Management app does that)? Then it will be complete and I will mark your answer as an answer. Thanks.